# Solana Program failing "An account required by the instruction is missing"

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, spl-token, rust, error

I am currently playing around with Solana Playground and have come across an error that I can not seem to fix.

I have written a program for native Solana in Rust with a little help from GPT4 which has the following tasks.

1. Check if a user has the balance of at least 1 of my SPL tokens
2. If the user has that balance then it should proceed with a transfer
3. If the user does not have that balance it should refund the transferred funds to the user

```
use solana_program::{
    account_info::{next_account_info, AccountInfo},
    entrypoint,
    entrypoint::ProgramResult,
    msg,
    program::{invoke, invoke_signed},
    program_error::ProgramError,
    pubkey::Pubkey,
    system_instruction,
};

use std::str::FromStr;
use solana_program::program_pack::Pack;

use spl_token::{
    state::Account as TokenAccount,
};

entrypoint!(process_instruction);

fn process_instruction(
    _program_id: &Pubkey,
    accounts: &[AccountInfo],
    _instruction_data: &[u8], // You can use this to pass the amount of lamports if needed
) -> ProgramResult {
    let accounts_iter = &mut accounts.iter();

    // Account 0: User's main account (payer)
    // Account 1: User's token account for the specified SPL token
    // Account 2: SPL Token program
    // Account 3: Destination account for lamports (if payment proceeds)
    let user_account = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
    msg!("User account: {:?}", user_account.key);

    let user_token_account = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
    msg!("User Token Account: {:?}", user_token_account.key);

    let token_program = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
    msg!("Token Program: {:?}", token_program.key);

    let destination_account = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
    msg!("Destination Account: {:?}", destination_account.key);

    // Check if the token account is a valid SPL Token account
    if *user_token_account.owner != *token_program.key {
        return Err(ProgramError::IncorrectProgramId);
    }

    msg!("User Token Account is a token program");

    // Unpack the token account data to get the token balance
    let token_account_info = TokenAccount::unpack(&user_token_account.try_borrow_data()?)?;

    msg!("Unpacked token account info");

    // Token mint address for '4CCHMonijtXvuGccPTC9h5TeDqFhhNvV5Ry42AxDjwhL'
    let expected_mint = Pubkey::from_str("4CCHMonijtXvuGccPTC9h5TeDqFhhNvV5Ry42AxDjwhL").unwrap();

    msg!("Unwrapped the expected mint");

    // Check if it's the correct token and if the user has at least 1 token
    if token_account_info.mint == expected_mint && token_account_info.amount >= 1_000_000_000 {
        msg!("User has the required token, proceeding with payment.");
        // Transfer lamports from the user's account to the destination account
        let transfer_instruction = system_instruction::transfer(
            user_account.key,
            destination_account.key,
            user_account.lamports(),
        );

        msg!("Created the transfer instruction to transfer: {:?} Lamports", user_account.lamports());
        
        invoke(
            &transfer_instruction,
            &[user_account.clone(), destination_account.clone()],
        )?;
        msg!("Invoked the transfer instruction.")
    } else {
        msg!("User does not have the required token, refunding lamports.");
        // Refund lamports back to the user's account
        let refund_instruction = system_instruction::transfer(
            user_account.key,
            destination_account.key,
            user_account.lamports(),
        );
        invoke_signed(
            &refund_instruction,
            &[user_account.clone(), destination_account.clone()],
            &[],
        )?;
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

This is my program, it logs everything until `User has the required token, proceeding with payment` then it simply errors out saying `An account required by the instruction is missing`

This is my test program:

```
const { PublicKey, Transaction, SystemProgram, LAMPORTS_PER_SOL } = web3;

// User's wallet and token account details (replace with actual details)
const userWallet = pg.wallet

const tokenMint = new PublicKey("4CCHMonijtXvuGccPTC9h5TeDqFhhNvV5Ry42AxDjwhL");

const userTokenAccountAddress = new PublicKey(
  "Ua8LGvSAXrBQ5kwNx8V23jMczHBuiXJDmMPUt8Dmtmh"
);
const destinationAccountAddress = new PublicKey(
  "3nt5zTTeHvaizE2YVBnoJN2NhD5DikxjFz4ntDPZimaV"
); // Destination account for lamports

// Program ID and SPL Token program ID
const programId = new PublicKey("2Sj6wQPZTX1biamdTZqxgaUPfQidDikApXr1BvgPVtXP");
const tokenProgramId = new PublicKey(
  "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA"
);

// Create a new transaction
let transaction = new Transaction();

// Add an instruction to the transaction
transaction.add(
  new web3.TransactionInstruction({
    keys: [
      { pubkey: userWallet.publicKey, isSigner: true, isWritable: true },
      { pubkey: userTokenAccountAddress, isSigner: false, isWritable: false },
      { pubkey: tokenProgramId, isSigner: false, isWritable: false },
      { pubkey: destinationAccountAddress, isSigner: false, isWritable: true },
    ],
    programId,
    data: Buffer.from([]), // Empty data for simplicity, modify if your program requires data
  })
);

// Transfer 0.5 SOL to the program (to be used or refunded by the program logic)
transaction.add(
  SystemProgram.transfer({
    fromPubkey: userWallet.publicKey,
    toPubkey: programId,
    lamports: 0.5 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
  })
);

// Send the transaction
try {
  let signature = await pg.connection.sendTransaction(transaction, [
    pg.wallet.keypair,
  ]);
  console.log("Transaction sent with signature", signature);
} catch (error) {
  console.error("Error sending transaction:", error);
}
```

The values are hardcoded for testing purposes. If anyone came across this it would be of great help to guide me towards a fix.

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: there are some things that are not clear to me :

1) your destination account doesn't seem to exist yet ? i guess it's not normal ?

2) you want to transfert spl tokens, but you input a number of lamports .... ?

Comment: The destination account now exists but I get the same error : (. I dont want to transfer SPL tokens, I want to transfer SOL, I want to check if the user has at least 1 of my SPL token and if that is the case transfer the SOL. If he doesnt then return the SOL or do nothing

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `system_instruction::transfer`, which uses the system program to only transfer lamports between accounts, you need to use `spl_token::instruction::transfer` to move SPL tokens between accounts.